# PHP Authentication with mysql

Tags: php

My name is Richat. I need your help.

I faced problem with login.
Below is my problem's details:

```
My PHP project is on SERVER A.
I use PC A access to my project on SERVER A and login successfully.
I use PC B access to my project on SERVER A and login successfully.
I use PC A to change my password.
I still can use my project on PC B (even if password had changed)
How to prevent this?
```

Note: I do not want PHP code checks DATABASE every transaction because this might take time if we don't change password.

What I want is: If we change password, let PHP check. If we not change, do not check it.

If you have any idea, please help me!

Comment: When you change password, your server should be able to delete all active session made. In your code you should be using session to check if any particular user is logged-in or not.

Comment: I hope .. PHP is not GOD to know automatically when ever u change password... You have to check before any execution or in particular interval ... or have to use session by storing bookmark after password change...

Comment: Thanks for your help! If we clear all active session, does it will clear all clients' session?

Comment: Best example for your question is facebook login your account through mobile and pc and change password in pc then you can understand what can you do.

Comment: In fact, I can check it when page is loading, but I don't want to check like this because if user not change his/her password, why we need to check. Do you have other ways to make our php code knows password has changed?